# disable scrolling untill animation is done

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple animation and I want to disable scrolling on the website

until this animation is done, it should be like a loader basically

**UPDATE**
thank you so much, but I have an issue with that sorry for not mention because I'm using a fixed position on a container to be fixed to do smooth scrolling, so when I use 'fixed' position for any element it doesn't seem to stick in the same place here is the full code

html

```html
    <main id="app">
     <div id="scroll-container" class="scroll-container">
      <div class="loader">
        <div class="loader__block"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </main>
```

CSS

```css
    body {
     overflow-x: hidden;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     background: $bg-color;
     user-select: none;
     font-family: 'Platform Regular';
    }

    #app {
     overflow: hidden;
     position: fixed;
     height: 100vh;
     width: 100vw;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
    }


    .scroll-container {  
      position: absolute;  
      overflow: hidden;
      z-index: 10;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;  
      backface-visibility: hidden;
    } 



    .loader {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999999;
        overflow: hidden;
    }


    .loader__block {
        position: absolute;
        width: 0%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: #111111;
        animation: go-left 4s cubic-bezier(.74, .06, .4, .92) forwards;
    }

    @keyframes go-left {
        0% {
            left: 0;
            width: 0%;
        }
        50% {
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
        100% {
            left: 100%;
            width: 0;
        }
```

these containers have a fixed position and overflow hidden because I'm making smooth page transition while scrolling and moving the 'y' position
here is also the js if it's going to help

```js
    function smoothScrolling() {
      const html = document.documentElement;
      const { body } = document;
      const scroller = {
        target: document.querySelector('#scroll-container'),
        ease: 0.06, // <= scroll speed
        endY: 0,
        y: 0,
        resizeRequest: 1,
        scrollRequest: 0,
      };
      let requestId = null;
      TweenLite.set(scroller.target, {
        rotation: 0.01,
        force3D: true,
      });
      function updateScroller() {
        const resized = scroller.resizeRequest > 0;
        if (resized) {
          const height = scroller.target.clientHeight;
          body.style.height = `${height}px`;
          scroller.resizeRequest = 0;
        }
        const scrollY = window.pageYOffset || html.scrollTop || body.scrollTop || 0;

        scroller.endY = scrollY;
        scroller.y += (scrollY - scroller.y) * scroller.ease;

        if (Math.abs(scrollY - scroller.y) < 0.05 || resized) {
          scroller.y = scrollY;
          scroller.scrollRequest = 0;
        }
        TweenLite.set(scroller.target, {
          y: -scroller.y,
        });
        requestId = scroller.scrollRequest > 0 ? requestAnimationFrame(updateScroller) : null;
      }
      function onScroll() {
        scroller.scrollRequest += 1;
        if (!requestId) {
          requestId = requestAnimationFrame(updateScroller);
        }
      }
      function onResize() {
        scroller.resizeRequest += 1;
        if (!requestId) {
          requestId = requestAnimationFrame(updateScroller);
        }
      }
      function onLoad() {
        updateScroller();
        window.focus();
        window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);
        document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
    }
```

Comment: While loading, you can add `overflow:hidden` to the `<body>` element. Then just remove it once you finish loading.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS rule `position: fixed;` on your div with class `loader` which makes it to always stay in the same place even if the page is scrolled.
as so:

```css
.loader {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999999;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}


.loader__block {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #111111;
    animation: go-left 4s cubic-bezier(.74, .06, .4, .92) forwards;
}

@keyframes go-left {
    0% {
        left: 0;
        width: 0%;
    }
    50% {
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        left: 100%;
        width: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<main id="app">
  <div id="scroll-container" class="scroll-container">
       <div class="loader">
  <div class="loader__block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TasteofLeaving I created a fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/sxa6b8fp/] with your updated example, the loader seems to only load halfway, is this the issue you're talking about?

Comment: That page doesn't exist, but i assume yes when i scroll it's scrolling normal and not fixed position, i think because the scroll-container also has a fixed position ?

Comment: here's the link, working: https://jsfiddle.net/sxa6b8fp/8 , I made a comment in the CSS section (line 22), the issue I observed occurred because you set the position of the `div` with class `scroll-container` to absolute.

Comment: Hello there, thank you for your efforts to help me, no this is not what i meant, the main container with id of app has a fixed position so i can't set any other div to have a fixed position got it ? so is there is any way i can achieve that ? the reason i set the main to have a fixed position is because i want to achieve smooth page scrolling like website for example  https://www.aristidebenoist.com/